# How to save Date Time without the time?

Tags: c#, datetime

How would i save the date time, with no time or preferably with a time stamp of 12:00, no matter what the time is at that moment?

I dont want to use `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`, because it will open up a whole lot of new  possible errors.

Comment: Where do you want to save the date? In database? or object of type Datetime class?

Comment: Time can either be stripped in code, persistence layer or database, which place seems most natural for the problem you are trying to solve ?

Comment: I'm using the MVVM structure. Sorry for not adding it to the tags. The thing is, later in out app we filter for this specific date and anything after 12:00 gets excluded in the query. So that being said, i need to do it at the set property. So either exclude the time or make it default to 12:00.

Comment: Just to clarify, are we talking about 12:00 HRS on 24 hr time or 0:00 HRS ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`DateTime` struct has a `Date` property that should serve your needs:

```
DateTime dateOnly = dateTime.Date;
```

Of course, it'll still inevitably contain a time part but you should be able to ignore it.

Comment: but this has a risk of becoming incorrect. For example, if you go from GMT to BST and midnight moves to 11pm of the previous day, then the Date part had changed.

Answer (score 2):

As other posters have said

```
DateTime.Now.Date
```

is the way to go.  However it is also worth thinking about whether you want to strip out timezone information to prevent problems occurring across different TZ on client\server machines.

You can use

```
var dateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Date.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 DateTime.Now.Date
```

or for myDate:

```
 myDate.Date
```

Comment: FYI, `DateTime.Today` is a useful shorthand for `DateTime.Now.Date`

Answer (score 1):

If you have any date

```
DateTime anyDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dateAtNoon = anyDate.Date.AddHours(12);
```

or if you want today you can use the shortcut

```
DateTime dateAtNoon = DateTime.Today.AddHours(12);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick with a preference to ts.Date

```
var ts = DateTime.Now;
var dateAtMidnight = ts.Date;
var dateAtNoon = ts.Date.AddHours(12);
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that by default a new date without time will default to 12:00 AM. Is this different from what you were suggesting ?

Comment: Correct.  I just find wrong to default it to 12P.M and Willem did not precised. If he live in Europe, 12:00 means 12:00PM

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx

If you want the current date, there is a slightly more readable:

```
DateTime.Today
```

but for a specific DateTime instance, then:

```
myDateTime.Date
```