# Is DateTime appropriate for storing only dates?

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I am designing an application that includes a simple "[tickler file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tickler_file)":

- The user can create notes for himself, and each note has an attached date.
- The user can ask the application to "check the tickler file" - this lists all notes that have been saved with a date matching today or earlier.
- For purposes of determining "today", the application simply believes whatever the OS claims the current date is.

This means that all timezone related complications are ignored. The application behaves as if there is only one timezone, and so by changing timezones it is potentially possible to introduce unexpected behavior. This is by design: I am trying to emulate a physical tickler file, which would have the same problem.

I am confused about what data type I should use for storing the date information. Should I use `DateTime`, or make my own `struct Date { public Day; public Month; public Year; }`?

I know about [using the `DateTime.Date` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4313014/1042555). However, `DateTime` internally stores data as [ticks since midnight 1/1 on 1 AD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#remarksToggle). This means it's impossible to actually store a date in `DateTime`, since every date is stored as *an instant on that date*. When we start talking about instants, it seems like we must now deal with complications related to timezones.

For instance, let's say a user in London, at 11 pm on 1 Jan 2016 creates a note that is supposed to come back up on 7 Jan 2016. Then this user travels to Alaska (and his computer automatically switches from UTC to AKST), and on 6 Jan 2016, 10 pm local time, lists notes that were saved for "today". Technically, it is now 7 Jan 2016 in the note's original timezone, so the task should appear. But it is only Jan 6 in the user's timezone, so it should not appear.

The MSDN seems to [echo my concern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Because the DateTime type represents both dates and times in a single type, it is important to avoid misinterpreting a date returned by the Date property as a date and time.

But how exactly am I supposed to make sure I don't misinterpret the date?

Comment: Don't you think that it would be nice that your application is based on UTC time ? if you are in London or somewhere else event occur based on UTC calculation. Like if you are london then when registering event take localtime and save utc time in DB or store. So even though use flies to some other timezone UTC will remain same even for future event. IF you are able to access DateTimeOffset then it will give you some of that support.

Comment: @dotnetstep Since timezone is irrelevant in a tickler file, I don't want to base my application on any time at all. (in fact, other functionality does deal with time, and it *is* based on UTC)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is appropriate to store dates in DateTime-stuructures. What you need to think about is the separation between **storing** of the dates and the **presentation** of the dates. You should use UTC for storing dates (use **DateTime.UtcNow** instead of **DateTime.Now**), and by doing this there will never be a problem with time zones as UTC keeps track of the offset to other timezones. When you present the date for the user, you can use time zone dependent data and display the correct date for that timezone. There is a method **DateTime.ToLocalTime** that you could use when displaying the date.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to confuse the effects of timezones and the effect of having TimeOfDay in `struct DateTime`.

A `DateTime` is perfect for storing dates only, just use `DateTime.Date` whenever you **store** a Date, thus setting HH:mm:ss to 00:00:00.
(This wastes a few Bytes of memeory which is mostly irrelevant in modern applications):

```
DateTime ticklerDate = DateTime.Now.Date; // 00:00h
```

Now your application has all these dates (without time and timezone information) and you can think about handling timezones (as you already did)