# How format date time field without hour portion in C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I am inserting date into database from text-boxes in MVC5 using C#. I try to get only date without the hour portion, but it saves like: 10/10/2019 12:00:00 AM when I only enter 10/10/2019 in the text box.  How I can format so save it without 12:00:00 AM part. I need to have the variable as Datetime.

this is the date property:

```
public DateTime Surrender_Effective_Date { get; set; }
```

and this is the code:

```
Licensedata.Surrender_Effective_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(Request["Surrender_Effective_Date"]);
```

I have tried this too but get same, save with hour portion.

```
lALegalLicensedata.Surrender_Effective_Date = DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToDateTime(Request["Surrender_Effective_Date"]).ToShortDateString());
```

My Database table dates are as string. I can't change it. and in my C# I need to have Datetime as some other issue.
when I debug I can see the value has 12:00:00 AM so if some way I can format this and send the date portion to DB I should be ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save Date Time without the time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312994/how-to-save-date-time-without-the-time)

Comment: You sure it's your code? In your DB is your field date or datetime?

Comment: You did not mentioned which data base and its version you are using?

Comment: DateTime always has a time portion, even if you truncate it in the input.

Comment: @AIG I edited my question.

Comment: If your database stores dates as strings, why are you converting Surrender_Effective_Date to a DateTime before saving it instead of saving it as a string?

Comment: @numaroth because my variable that is Surrender_Effective_Date  is Datetime, I can't have it as string because some other use.

Answer (score 1):

Make your DB table column datatype from `DateTime` to `Date` .. Hopefully your problem will solve ..

If your column datatype is `NVarchar` or `Varchar` type .. then when inserting data into database convert it to string ..

```
dbcommand.Parameter.Add("Surrender_Effective_Date",DBType.Nvarchar).Value=Surrender_Effective_Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

And while comparing with another datetime in `codebehind` compare with `date` only

```
if(Surrender_Effective_Date.Date==anotherDate.Date)
{
 //Rest of code goes here
}
```

When showing value in UI .. you need to format it again

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) more formats are available

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have the column as DateTime, then you -have- to store it in the database with the time, which by default if one isn't set, is midnight. This is how DateTime values are designed. What you'll have to do when you retrieve the data from the database, is strip the [information mentioned in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312994/how-to-save-date-time-without-the-time) by storing the date in a string.

Otherwise, change the Datetime column in your database to a Date column.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you need to override the behaviour of ToString in order to remove time portion.

```
    CultureInfo ci=new CultureInfo("en-US");
    ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "";
    ci.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "";

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `TimeSpan` to show just time and property `TimeOfDay` of struct `DateTime` to get just time:

```
var ts = DateTime.Now;    
TimeSpan timeOnly = ts.TimeOfDay;
```